# Postgres' planning takes unproportional time for execution

Tags: postgresql

postgres 9.6 running on amazon RDS.

I have 2 tables:

1. aggregate events - big table with 6 keys (ids)
2. campaign metadata - small table with campaign definition.

I join the 2 in order to filter on metadata like campaign-name.

The query is in order to get a report of displayed breakdown by campaign channel and date ( date is daily ).

No FK and not null. The report table has multiple lines per day per campaigns ( because the aggregation is based on 6 attribute key ).

When i join , query plan grow to 10s ( vs 300ms)

```
explain analyze select c.campaign_channel as channel,date as day , sum( displayed )  as displayed
from report_campaigns c
left join events_daily r on r.campaign_id = c.c_id
where  provider_id = 7726 and c.p_id = 7726 and c.campaign_name <> 'test'
and date >= '20170513 12:00' and date <= '20170515 12:00'
group by c.campaign_channel,date;
                                                                                         QUERY PLAN
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 GroupAggregate  (cost=71461.93..71466.51 rows=229 width=22) (actual time=104.189..114.788 rows=6 loops=1)
   Group Key: c.campaign_channel, r.date
   ->  Sort  (cost=71461.93..71462.51 rows=229 width=18) (actual time=100.263..106.402 rows=31205 loops=1)
         Sort Key: c.campaign_channel, r.date
         Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 3206kB
         ->  Hash Join  (cost=1092.52..71452.96 rows=229 width=18) (actual time=22.149..86.955 rows=31205 loops=1)
               Hash Cond: (r.campaign_id = c.c_id)
               ->  Append  (cost=0.00..70245.84 rows=29948 width=20) (actual time=21.318..71.315 rows=31205 loops=1)
                     ->  Seq Scan on events_daily r  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=0.005..0.005 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Filter: ((date >= '2017-05-13 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-05-15 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (provider_id =
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events_daily_20170513 r_1  (cost=685.36..23913.63 rows=1 width=20) (actual time=17.230..17.230 rows=0 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (provider_id = 7726)
                           Filter: ((date >= '2017-05-13 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-05-15 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Rows Removed by Filter: 13769
                           Heap Blocks: exact=10276
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_daily_20170513_full_idx  (cost=0.00..685.36 rows=14525 width=0) (actual time=2.356..2.356 rows=13769 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (provider_id = 7726)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events_daily_20170514 r_2  (cost=689.08..22203.52 rows=14537 width=20) (actual time=4.082..21.389 rows=15281 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (provider_id = 7726)
                           Filter: ((date >= '2017-05-13 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-05-15 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=10490
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_daily_20170514_full_idx  (cost=0.00..685.45 rows=14537 width=0) (actual time=2.428..2.428 rows=15281 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (provider_id = 7726)
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on events_daily_20170515 r_3  (cost=731.84..24128.69 rows=15409 width=20) (actual time=4.297..22.662 rows=15924 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (provider_id = 7726)
                           Filter: ((date >= '2017-05-13 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date <= '2017-05-15 12:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
                           Heap Blocks: exact=11318
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on events_daily_20170515_full_idx  (cost=0.00..727.99 rows=15409 width=0) (actual time=2.506..2.506 rows=15924 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (provider_id = 7726)
               ->  Hash  (cost=1085.35..1085.35 rows=574 width=14) (actual time=0.815..0.815 rows=582 loops=1)
                     Buckets: 1024  Batches: 1  Memory Usage: 37kB
                     ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on report_campaigns c  (cost=12.76..1085.35 rows=574 width=14) (actual time=0.090..0.627 rows=582 loops=1)
                           Recheck Cond: (p_id = 7726)
                           Filter: ((campaign_name)::text <> 'test'::text)
                           Heap Blocks: exact=240
                           ->  Bitmap Index Scan on report_campaigns_provider_id  (cost=0.00..12.62 rows=577 width=0) (actual time=0.062..0.062 rows=582 loops=1)
                                 Index Cond: (p_id = 7726)
 Planning time: 9651.605 ms
 Execution time: 115.092 ms


result:
 channel  |         day         | displayed
----------+---------------------+-----------
 Pin      | 2017-05-14 00:00:00 |   43434
 Pin      | 2017-05-15 00:00:00 |   3325325235
```

Comment: Please post the table schema of joined tables, their constraints (unique, primary key, etc). Please describe what the query is supposed to achieve in plain english words (there may be other ways to write it). Which columns can be null? Nulls usually mean zero-to-one or zero-to-many relationships. What about using foreign key constraints instead of nulls? What are your functional dependencies? Are the tables in 3rd normal form? Do you have an index on `date_trunc('day',date)`? If possible, please post a few rows of example data before and after the join for the 3 tables. Forget unused columns.

Comment: I added more data and simplify the query.
I dont understand why you need the describe and info about FK and nulls.
Adding too much data make it hard to read the question.
You can see all the important  information in the query plan. You can see the index.

Comment: You will probably get a better response if you post that to the Postgres mailing list. I'm sure the Postgres devs would be very interested.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name what makes you think that? How can you tell that from only the query plan?

Comment: @flutter: I would assume the devs consider 10 seconds planing time for such a simple statement a bug.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name oh wow, i misread the timings. You're right. OP should send a description to the devs. This planning time is really too high.

Answer (score 0):

I seems to me this is because of summation forcing pre-computation before left joining.

Solution could be to impose filtering WHERE clauses in two nested sub-SELECT prior to left-joining and summation.

Hope this works:

```
SELECT channel, day, sum( displayed )
FROM
(SELECT campaign_channel AS channel, date AS day, displayed, p_id AS c_id
 FROM report_campaigns WHERE p_id = 7726 AND campaign_name <> 'test' AND date >= '20170513 12:00' AND date <= '20170515 12:00') AS c,
(SELECT * FROM events_daily WHERE campaign_id = 7726) AS r
LEFT JOIN r.campaign_id = c.c_id
GROUP BY channel, day;
```

Comment: sub-select do work, but i dont want to use sub-select because its make my report engine more complex (i simplified the query for the question. the real queries are much more complexed and involve few tables).

Comment: then perhaps one solution would be to remove the sum, execute the entire query as a single subquery and then sum on the end-result. also have you primary keyed and indexed?

Comment: Sorry - even simple join dosnt work.
usa_events=> explain analyze select campaign_id ,  spent   as spent from events_daily r left join report_campaigns c on r.campaign_id = c.c_id  where  date >= '20170720' and date < '20170721' ;

 Planning time: 8393.337 ms
 Execution time: 0.132 ms
(11 rows)

Comment: I apologise but I am unable to read and understand you, could you reformulate your comment? For example would you mind posting a small sample dataset and a copy of the query? Thank you :)