# postgres how to debug why planning time is too long?

Tags: postgresql

version - postgres 9.6.

I were not so clear in [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44471782/postgres-planning-takes-unproportional-time-for-execution) i asked in past and someone already answer there, so i thought best will be to post new question with more clear info and be more specific about my question.

Trying to join event table with dimension table.
event table is a daily partition (3k children) table with check constraints.The event table has 72 columns (i suspect that this is the issue).

I simplify the query in order to demonstrate the question (in practice range is wider and i query field from both tables).

You can see that for this simple query - the **plan** take almost 10 seconds (my question is about plan time and not execution time).
If i query direct on the child table ( please dont advice to use union on all child in range ) query plan is few ms.

```
explain analyze select campaign_id ,  spent   as spent from events_daily r left join report_campaigns c on r.campaign_id = c.c_id  where  date >= '20170720' and date < '20170721' ;
                                                                      QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..28.88 rows=2 width=26) (actual time=0.021..0.021 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Append  (cost=0.00..12.25 rows=2 width=26) (actual time=0.003..0.003 rows=0 loops=1)
         ->  Seq Scan on events_daily r  (cost=0.00..0.00 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.002..0.002 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((date >= '2017-07-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2017-07-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
         ->  Seq Scan on events_daily_20170720 r_1  (cost=0.00..12.25 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.000..0.000 rows=0 loops=1)
               Filter: ((date >= '2017-07-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2017-07-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
   ->  Index Only Scan using report_campaigns_campaign_idx on report_campaigns c  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
         Index Cond: (c_id = r.campaign_id)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 8393.337 ms
 Execution time: 0.132 ms
(11 rows)

explain analyze select campaign_id ,  spent   as spent from events_daily_20170720 r left join report_campaigns c on r.campaign_id = c.c_id  where  date >= '20170720' and date < '20170721' ;
                                                                   QUERY PLAN
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Nested Loop Left Join  (cost=0.29..20.57 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.008..0.008 rows=0 loops=1)
   ->  Seq Scan on events_daily_20170720 r  (cost=0.00..12.25 rows=1 width=26) (actual time=0.007..0.007 rows=0 loops=1)
         Filter: ((date >= '2017-07-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone) AND (date < '2017-07-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone))
   ->  Index Only Scan using report_campaigns_campaign_idx on report_campaigns c  (cost=0.29..8.31 rows=1 width=8) (never executed)
         Index Cond: (c_id = r.campaign_id)
         Heap Fetches: 0
 Planning time: 0.242 ms
 Execution time: 0.059 ms


\d events_daily_20170720
 date                      | timestamp without time zone |
Check constraints:
    "events_daily_20170720_date_check" CHECK (date >= '2017-07-20 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone AND date < '2017-07-21 00:00:00'::timestamp without time zone)
Inherits: events_daily

show constraint_exclusion;
 constraint_exclusion
----------------------
 on
```

When running ltrace it seems that it run this thousands of time on each field (hint that it run on all patitions tables for the plan) :

```
strlen("process")                                                                                                                                                    = 7
memcpy(0x0b7aac10, "process", 8)                                                                                                                                     = 0x0b7aac10
strlen("channel")                                                                                                                                                    = 7
memcpy(0x0b7aac68, "channel", 8)                                                                                                                                     = 0x0b7aac68
strlen("deleted")                                                                                                                                                    = 7
memcpy(0x0b7aacc0, "deleted", 8)                                                                                                                                     = 0x0b7aacc0
strlen("old_spent")                                                                                                                                                  = 9
memcpy(0x0b7aad18, "old_spent", 10)
```

Comment: This is due to big number of child tables. Consider using pg_partman or pg_pathman https://pgconf.ru/media/2017/04/03/20170316H2_Musin-Ivanov.pdf

Comment: My experience with planning time is that it can vary very much depending on load on database or instance. Especially when heavy load on database causes long waits on CPUs due to disk IO. If you see so long planning times permanently it can mean you have very weak or constantly overloaded server.

Comment: This is a test db , nothing run on it except my queries.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you have too many partitions.

As [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-partitioning.html#DDL-PARTITIONING-CAVEATS) warns:

> All constraints on all partitions of the master table are examined during constraint exclusion,
>   so large numbers of partitions are likely to increase query planning time considerably.
>   Partitioning using these techniques will work well with up to perhaps a hundred partitions;
>   don't try to use many thousands of partitions.

You should try to reduce the number of partitions by using a longer time interval for each partition.

Alternatively, you could try to change the application code to directly access the correct partition if possible, but that might prove difficult and it removes many advantages that partitioning should bring.

Comment: So what can you do when you want to have daily partitions ? 
Its seems that number of columns in the table (not number of selected columns) dramatically affect the planning time, so with one 3 columns table its few ms and with 72 columns its become 8 seconds.
Why planning care about columns in the table when they are not selected? why planning care about tables that are not in the check constraints ?

Comment: I don't see a connection with the number of columns. In your second query you access `events_daily_20170720` rather than `events_daily`, so the optimizer doesn't have to examine all the partitions. That makes the difference.

Comment: I did a test with few columns and thousands of partitions - the planner time was milis . Than add more 50 columns ( to the table . not to the select ) and planner time change to seconds.

Comment: From that I'd say that the combination of many columns and many partitions causes the problem. I'd try to reduce one of these numbers.